# Writing the filtering query to ignore some strings

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi im obtaining data from a table through a query.. i need to omit some of the data types, currently i cant write the query for that

```
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| aut_id | aut_name             | country   | home_city      |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
| AUT001 | William Norton       | UK        | Cambridge      |
| AUT002 | William Maugham      | Canada    | Toronto        |
| AUT003 | William Anthony      | UK        | Leeds          |
| AUT004 | S.B.Swaminathan      | India     | Bangalore      |
| AUT005 | Thomas Morgan        | Germany   | Arnsberg       |
| AUT006 | Thomas Merton        | USA       | New York       |
| AUT007 | Piers Gibson         | UK        | London         |
| AUT008 | Nikolai Dewey        | USA       | Atlanta        |
| AUT009 | Marquis de Ellis     | Brazil    | Rio De Janerio |
| AUT010 | Joseph Milton        | USA       | Houston        |
| AUT011 | John Betjeman Hunter | Australia | Sydney         |
| AUT012 | Evan Hayek           | chillie   | Chillie        |
| AUT013 | E. Howard            | Spain     | Madrid         |
| AUT014 | C. J. Wilde          | UK        | London         |
| AUT015 | Butler Andre         | Austria   | Florida        |
+--------+----------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

i want to omit brazil, australia and chillie.. i tried query similer to below but it dint work

```
SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
 AND d.country NOT LIKE 'brazil' OR 'Austria' OR 'Chillie'
 GROUP BY d.country
```

but it works for one country like this

```
SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
 AND d.country NOT LIKE 'brazil'
 GROUP BY d.country
```

can anybody help me to do the filtering and get rid of the terms i want

Comment: Thanks for all the useful replies guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
 AND d.country NOT IN ('brazil', 'Austria', 'Chillie')
 GROUP BY d.country
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this...
[edit]

```
 SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
     AND d.country NOT LIKE 'brazil' AND d.country NOT LIKE 'Austria' AND d.country NOT LIKE 'Chillie'
     GROUP BY d.country;
```

Above works but other people answers are best...!

Comment: But this query is WRONG! It should be AND all the way, not OR d.country NOT LIKE 'Chillie'.

Answer (score 1):

NOT IN will work for you:

```
SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM tbl
 where d.country NOT in ('brazil','Austria','Chillie')
 GROUP BY d.country
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
AND d.country NOT IN ('brazil', 'Austria', 'Chillie')
GROUP BY d.country
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive using `AND`

```
 SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
 AND d.country <> 'brazil' AND d.country <>'Austria' AND d.country <>'Chillie'
 GROUP BY d.country
```

OR `NOT IN`

```
 SELECT d.country, COUNT(*) AS number FROM ..............
 AND d.country NOT IN ('brazil','Austria','Chillie')
 GROUP BY d.country
```